# What was Bolas trying to do with the mana absorbed from the Conflux?

Tags: books, magic, magical-theory, magic-the-gathering

In the Magic: The Gathering book, *Alara Unbroken*, Nicol Bolas attempts to absorb a massive amount of mana created from a planar catastrophe, [Alara's Conflux](http://mtg.gamepedia.com/Conflux_(event)) - in an attempt to regain his former power levels. He succeeds in harvesting the essence of most of the Maelstrom, but finally he is driven off.
[image]

The question I have is this: what was he planning to do with the mana? Sure, it's a large amount of power, but if he simply wanted to use it as a raw source of fuel, then it's not a very maintainable source of power. He will use it up over time. Which leads me to believe that he was going attempt to use it for something else; possibly for mutating his spark.
Has it been hinted at in canon, and did he retain the power after being driven from Alara?

Answer (score 1):

His [character page](https://magic.wizards.com/en/story/planeswalkers/nicol-bolas) on the *Magic: The Gathering* website states that he wanted to permanently regain his pre-mending power.

> Unknown to all but Nicol, the shards of Alara are reconverging into a single plane, and when that happens, he wants all-out planar war.
>
> Why? His obsessive need to regain the godlike powers he had before The Mending. Back then, Planeswalkers were ageless shapeshifters whose supremacy was limited only by their experience and knowledge.
>
> This elder dragon had that power torn away from him, and he will go to any lengths to get it back. For Nicol Bolas, all the power in the universe is not enough.

The website's page for [Alara](https://magic.wizards.com/en/story/planes/alara) repeats this and states that a unified Alara is also part of Bolas's greater plan.

> Nicol Bolas, the ancient dragon Planeswalker, planned this all along. He came to Alara to feed on its rich mana and, in one massive ritual, restore its lost power as part of his multiplanar plan.